# two questions about orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

1. when I run my app on the emulator and switch to landscape my activity redraws without problems, but when I switch back to portrait, the screen orientation changes but my app does not redraw itself. why?
2. so I tried to intercept the orientation change event and redraw manually, but when I override `onConfigurationChanged` in my activity (and just call `super` from it), the emulator stops responding to F11 (switch orientation) key. why? EDIT: this one was because I did not have configChanges attribute set on my activity.

thanks for any help!

Comment: when you override the onConfigurationChanged did you set android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"??

Comment: I did not have it, after I added this attribute the second problem went away, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about that problem because it's not your application coding problem it's problem with emulator.

I also faced this problem but when I run my application in my device it runs without any problem..

```
In mine it appears to only do this for the Google APIs (Google Inc.) 2.3.3 API Level-10 AVD.
 The normal Android 2.3.3 seems to rotate as expected. Not sure if this is a bug or what.
```